# Azure diagnostics configuration is wiped off after re-deploying

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-diagnostics

I have a project which I upgraded the Azure SDK to 2.5. I did the diagnostics changes and configured the diagnostics after deploying. After couple of re-deployments, I noticed that the diagnostics configuration is gone. It was no longer recording anything, so I had to re-configure the diagnostics from the visual studio. I use the TFS online with azure deployment workflow to deploy.
What am I doing wrong? Do I have to re-configure the diagnostics after re-deploying?

Answer (score 0):

VSO currently doesn't implement the new WAD architecture, but the plan is to start supporting it with the next Azure SDK release.  In the meantime you will need to manually apply the WAD configuration to your service using Visual Studio or Powershell.

Comment: I did enable the diagnostics using the server explorer after deploying. Do I have to do it after each re-deployment?